# Can I omit "one" in the following case?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

> Rich people's lives are the most complicated (ones)—and also the most
>   meaningless (ones).

Can I omit both? If not, which one should I keep?

Comment: You can (and, IMO, should) omit both.

Comment: @janoChen yes none of the *ones* is required ;)

Comment: Sorry to be persnickety, but why is there a 'but' in your sentence? **complicated** usually has a negative denotation as does **meaningless**, so unless there's additional context that's missing, it should really be, "Rich people's lives are the most complicated and also the most meaningless."

Comment: @K - you're right I fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can eliminate both *ones*. Your sentence would look like this:

> Rich people's lives are the most complicated — and also the most meaningless.

This reads fluently and looks better than the original on paper.

To make the sentence read better, you could consider removing the *also*, as @J.R. [commented](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/194449/can-i-omit-one-in-the-following-case/194677#comment408652_194677). Doing this will give:

> Rich people's lives are the most complicated — and the most meaningless.

Go minimalism!

Comment: One could argue the "also" is redundant and that the sentence may read better without it.

Comment: @J.R.- you're right, however I wanted to keep the answer in the context of the question. I will add a section that covers this.

Comment: I understand that "reads fluently and looks good on paper" ≠ "can't be improved any further". However, I can imagine someone interpreting it that way, hence my comment. :^)

Comment: @J.R. - changed from 'good' to 'better than the original'. Feel free to edit this question to improve it further.